# Oracle : A specific name for the output of an SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i create something so that when i query like:

```
select EODC_DATE from dual;
```

I get output :

```
EODC_DATE  
09-JAN-2018
```

where `EODC_DATE` is fetching the value from  table `EOD_CONTROL`  and EOD_CONTROL table looks like below

```
select  EOD_DATE from EOD_CONTROL
```

output :

```
EOD_DATE   
09-JAN-2018
```

Comment: Could you provide more details to your question? I don't understand what you are asking to do. Are you looking to join the two tables on a given column?

Comment: Are you looking for column aliasing, displaying a different name for a column? E.g. `select EOD_DATE as EODC_DATE from EOD_CONTROL`

Comment: create a scalar function

Comment: Rephrased the question

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title:

> Oracle : A specific name for the output of an SQL query

The output of a SQL query is the **projection**.

Comment: Thanks, i did not mean that. Please look into the details

Comment: Yeah your details aren't any more help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand the question, but maybe alias the output from `EOD_CONTROL` ?

```
select  EOD_DATE  as EODC_DATE from EOD_CONTROL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION EODC_DATE
RETURN DATE
AS
  vret DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT eod_date
    INTO   vret
    FROM   eod_control;

    RETURN vret;
END;
```

Your select statement hopefully returns a single row, otherwise you need to handle it appropriately